# QuickBlox - Create user account using facebook

Tags: quickblox

Can I get my users to signup to my app using just their Facebook connect details, or do they need to create a QuickBlox account first and then join that to their Facebook account?

I am ideally looking for a Facebook connect scenario so users don't need another signup process.

thanks for any info / help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 1 step

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization

**Sign In using Facebook/Twitter dialog form** item

QuickBlox iOS SDK will show you Facebook login dialog

Also you can try  **Sign In using Facebook/Twitter access token**.
Just provide to QuickBlox your Facebook access token

Comment: Thanks Igor,  I am working via the REST api rather that iOS but i have found how to do it

Comment: Please what is the the Facebook access token(how can i get the access token ?)

Comment: And how to make usign the QB REST API?

Comment: You can obtain FB access token after login to Facebook